# Nuxt.js: Setting publicPath Causes Page Not Found

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

### Goal

Set up a `Nuxt.js` app to run in a subdirectory.

### Problem

Hitting the configured `publicPath` shows "This page could not be found" clearly rendered by Nuxt.js even though the inspector shows that all the files are successfully loaded.

[image]

### Context

**nuxt.config.js**

```
build: {
    publicPath: 'https://qa.nicetry.com/apps/nuxt'
}
```

I run `yarn run build` and everything works correctly.

Then, I hit `https://qa.nicetry.com/apps/nuxt` in the browser and see the lovely "This page could not be found" message. No console errors.

Even more confusing, I hit the "Back to the home page" link on this error page which points to `https://qa.nicetry.com` and it works. Even the app links work (i.e. `https://qa.nicetry.com/test/route` which should really be `https://qa.nicetry.com/apps/nuxt/test/route`). When I refresh, everything breaks as expected.

`nuxt 2.4.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set router base 
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#base

```
export default {
  router: {
    base: '/app/'
  }
}
```

Comment: Even after adding the router.base, the error persists.    ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                                                                │
   │                                                                                     │
   │   Error: No build files found in xxxxx/dist/dist/server.         │
   │   Use either `nuxt build` or `builder.build()` or start nuxt in development mode

Comment: @jolly u have a totally different issue, create new question with minimal rfeproduction

Comment: Maybe with new version of Vue, the behaviour of problem has changed. But this happens whenever I set a public path in Nuxt.